# Ordering alphabetically on stacked list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two lists on my website depending on what is selected from the 1st list will bring back a second list, i am trying to find a way to order the second list in this case #towns as at the moment it just brings back the towns in order of ID how would i alter this code to order my towns alphabetically?

```
       <script type="text/javascript">

 $('#cities_id').on('change', function(e){
   console.log(e);

   var cities_id = e.target.value;
   var response = '';
   document.getElementById('towns').disabled = false;

   $.get('/ajax-subcat?cities_id=' +cities_id, function(data){
       $('#towns').empty();
       $('#towns').append('<option selected disabled>-- Select a Town (optional) --</option>');


       $.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
           $('#towns').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');


       })
   })


 });



 </script>
```

Comment: Can't `/ajax-subcat?cities_id=whatever` return a properly ordered list?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sort` ;

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.subcatObj.name.toUpperCase();
    var textB = b.subcatObj.name.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
$.each(data, function(index, subcatObj){
  $('#towns').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
});
```

Also, It could be better to apply sort process in the serverside.

Comment: That makes the list disappear unfortunately

Comment: Would you share the json of data ?